# Setting header while sending a record to a topic in kafka-stream

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need to process a ***request*** record in kafka-stream and also need to tell the sender the ***response*** of the processing. I created a Rest endpoint to receive the request. This endpoint uses spring-kafka's **ReplyingKafkaTemplate**, which sends request on a topic and wait for response on another topic. correlation id header is used to correlate the request and response.

How can I set the correlation id header in the ***response*** record in my kafka-stream code is sending after processing the ***request*** record?

Answer (score 0):

Add a stream processor to copy the input header to the output record.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html